# C# store a string variable to a text file .txt

Tags: c#, string, text, store, text-files

1. How can i store the contents of a string variable to a text file ?
2. How can i search in a string variable for specific text for example find if the word book is in the string?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To save the file to text you can do:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\your_path\your_file", Your_contents);
```

To Search for something in the string:

```
var position = Your_string.IndexOf("Book");
```

If position equals -1 then what you are searching for isn't there.

Answer (score 6):

```
File.WriteAllText("MyFile.txt", myString); // Write all string to file
var wordBookIndex = myString.IndexOf("book"); // If the string is found, index != -1
```

Answer (score 6):

In the off chance you are actually stumped on where to find this information, it's as simple as:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(myPathToTheFile, myStringToWrite);
```

To find a string within another string, you would simply do this:

```
myString.Contains(someOtherString); // boolean
myString.IndexOf(someOtherString); // find the 0 based index of the target string
```

Answer (score 1):

System.IO namespace has various methods and classes for file (and other) IO, this one may serve your purpose easily:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx

As for searching inside a single string, use String.IndexOf:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**answer to 1 question**

make use of **System.IO namespace** in that there are not class availabe to wirte the text in file

**answer to 2 question**

you can use **Regular expression** or make use of **IndexOf** function to serach specific word in string